# get json data based on object name

Tags: java, json

May be it's a simple task for some one.

I've json like below.

```
{
  "address": {
    "state": "World",
    "address": "infinite space, 000",
    "city": "Android city",
    "address2": {
      "state": "World2",
      "address": "infinite space2, 002",
      "city": "Android city2",
      "address3": {
        "state": "World3",
        "address": "infinite space3, 003",
        "city": "Android city3"
      }
    }
  },
  "valid": {
    "state": "World",
    "address": "infinite space, 000",
    "city": "Android city",
    "valid2": {
      "state": "World2",
      "address": "infinite space2, 002",
      "city": "Android city2",
      "valid3": {
        "state": "World3",
        "address": "infinite space3, 003",
        "city": "Android city3"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is a sample structure. Some times may have many objects inside of one object. I know this is a bad format of JSON but i've to achieve my requirement by using this only :-(.

My requirement is: when we sending the object name like `address3` or `valid3` to a method as argument. My method have to return `key` and `value` of object (Which we passed as argument). Any one know, how to achieve this in Java?

Comment: Parse the json (could be a generic format that basically uses maps and lists - the actual classes depend on the framework you're using) and then do a lookup. That should be straight forward and I'll leave the details up to you.

Comment: Which JSON library are you using ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution

```
private void parseJson(JSONObject jsonObject, String objName){

    try {

        for(int i = 0; i < jsonObject.length(); i++){


            if(jsonObject.get(jsonObject.names().getString(i)) instanceof JSONObject){

                JSONObject  singleObj = new JSONObject(jsonObject.get(jsonObject.names().getString(i)).toString());

                Iterator<String> keys= singleObj.keys();
                while (keys.hasNext()){

                    String keyValue = keys.next();
                    final String valueString = singleObj.getString(keyValue);

                    if(!isJSONObjectOrString(valueString)){

                        if(keyValue.contains(objName) || valueString.contains(objName)
                                || jsonObject.names().getString(i).contains(objName)){
                            Log.e("objectName", jsonObject.names().getString(i));
                            Log.e(keyValue, valueString);
                        }

                    }

                }

                parseJson(singleObj);
            }
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the `JSON` and convert the result into a `HashMap<String,String>`

Here is sample code for this `JSON object` .

```
public HashMap<String,String> getKeyValuePairs(JSONObject json,String key){
          HashMap<String,String> jsonHashList=new  HashMap<String,String>();   
          JSONObject desiredJSON = json.get(key);
          Iterator<?> keys = desiredJSON.keys();
     while( keys.hasNext() ) {
        String key2 = (String)keys.next();
        if ( desiredJSON.get(key2) instanceof JSONObject ) {
               String value = desiredJSON.get(key2);
               jsonHashList.add(key2,value);
        }
    }

    return jsonHashList;
 }
```

Note : In this case key is assumed to be at level one of passed `JSON` so if you want to pass any `JSON` to get it's key values separated pass the Level One `JSON`.

Comment: Hi Rohan Kadu, thank you for your help. I've used your solution by passing my whole `json` and `address3` as arguments but i'm getting `org.json.JSONException: No value for address3` error

Comment: This is what I added in note. That you have to pass one level converter. In your case 'address3' is child of 'address2' so it will work when you pass JSON object of key 'address2'